# how can we bring more attention towards Questions related to SharePoint configuration & Admin

Tags: discussion, support, questions

This has happened to me for [This Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218695/do-i-need-to-buy-and-set-up-domain-for-apps-while-doing-server-side-integration), As questions related to SP configuration are less active because people are mostly dependent on the MSDN links for reference. This leads to a reluctant approach by most of the forum members to answer these questions.

So, How can we bring more attention and make these questions equally important likewise other development related questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately StackExchange community has provision for this. The provision is called as [Bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) management.

**Bounty is one of the way.**

You can start bounty on the question you want to get more attention. Although bounty does not guaranty the answer but it will capture more attention.

Once you start bounty on any question it will be shown up into `Featured` tab.

[image]

Read everything about bounty [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think your question is a good example of "SharePoint configuration & administration" (a bit of that below). It's a question of integrating two Microsoft products and how the hosting of the products should be done considered. Also as MS Dynamics is an addition, a piece that *can* be integrated to SharePoint - receiving the best available information about its configuration might not be available exactly here. You should consider asking the same question in different circles, like in [Microsoft Dynamics Community Forums](https://community.dynamics.com/f).

Personally I have answered and received answer for SharePoint's configuration and administration related questions, and I feel these are widely approached topics in general. However, a configuration, as the name suggests, becomes easily almost unique. Combining that to administrative perspective you might be creating your own snowflake soon.

I asked [a question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190238/configure-alternate-access-via-internet-to-intranet-web-applications-with-hnsc) about a custom access to SP which was a snowflake of my own, but never received an answer. A ~year from that, I've recently succeeded in the task (well, there maybe was 11 months when I didn't try to get this done) and hope to share the results soon'ish. However, what I'm after is that sharing the how-to for a quite specific setup is rarely done, which is why even seasoned community members might not be available to help completely with the requests.

Your questions:

> How can we [...] make these questions equally important

Especially each new question is (equally) important. Answering for how to create a document library is just easier and something you can do when e.g. travelling in a train, so there's more often a (quick) answer for such questions.

> How can we bring more attention

See: Aakash Morya's answer.